# Django: How do I update a model after a view has been rendered?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a view that displays a list of models. Some of the properties of some of the models need to be updated after the view has been rendered: that is, the user is expected to see the original, unchanged values on first visit and the updated values on successive visits (or upon page reload).

I thought I could achieve this with class-based generic views. The [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#performing-extra-work) hints at "doing some extra work before or **after** calling the generic view" (emphasis mine), but all examples given affect the models before it is displayed.

I looked into signals, but to no avail.

Spawning an asynchronous task is an option, but, since all I need to do is update a field in a few models (likely one or none) and save them, it seems overkill for the task at hand.

One could use an ajax request to trigger the update, or a custom template tag to display the relevant fields and update them thereafter. I dislike both, as they move application logic into the view layer. The ajax technique also adds the overhead of a second request.

Yet, I seem to have no other choices, or do I? Is there a more practical technique for plugging into the generic view or the request and execute extra logic after the template has been rendered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need for anything clever here. Rendering a template doesn't need to be the end of the view - that only comes when you actually *return* that as a response. They don't have to be in the same step.

So :

```
def my_view(request, params):
    #...do something...
    response = render_to_response('my_template.html', {'foo': bar})
    # ...do something after rendering...
    return response
```

Now, if you need to do this in a lot of views, you might want to do it in a decorator:

```
def my_decorator(view):
    def my_func(request, params):
        response = view(request, params)
        #...do something after rendering...
        return response
    return my_func
```

now you can decorate your views with `@my_decorator` and the action will be performed after rendering.

... or, it just occurred to me, if you want to do it in *every* view, you could do it in a middleware (just define the [`process-response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/#process-response) method).

**Edit after comment** Class-based generic views use the new TemplateResponse class. You can add tasks that happen after the template is actually rendered with a [post-render callback](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/template-response/#post-render-callbacks).

Comment: While that should work for the case where you do the view work manually, it doesn't seem to work if you delegate visualization to a generic view (I only tried with a class-based generic view, but function-based generic views are deprecated anyway), because on returning from the view the template has not yet been parsed, so it will see the updated models.

Comment: `render_to_response` is just `render` in django >2.0

Answer (score 0):

Catch the return value from the view or function, do some processing, then kick it up the stack.

```
def foo(*args):
  ret = bar(*args)
  do_something()
  return ret
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. When the original view returns, the template has not yet been parsed, so the modifications show up in the first visualization.

Answer (score 0):

Could you grab two copies of the object, modifying and saving one while passing the other (unmodified and outdated) one to the view?

I haven't used class-based generic views yet, so I can't give you a specific example.

Comment: That should work, but it implies passing a (potentially very long) list to the template. I'd prefer a solution with less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Django also comes with a [built-in signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#request-finished) `request_finished`, that is sent AFTER django finished processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

If your project already use celery, you could create a task to update the model and 
and call

```
your_task.delay()
```

You could use the countdown argument to specify an elapsed before launching the task.

If you are not using celery chances are that you will in the future :)